# Seconds into Hours, Minutes, Seconds

Tags: java

I am just starting to learn java and i have a problem that seems to have a simple answer...

`System.out.print("Your time in hours/minutes/seconds is: ");
    System.out.print(+hours);
    System.out.print(":");
    System.out.print(+minutes);
    System.out.print(":");
    System.out.print(+seconds);`

How can i get the final product in one line of code without getting a compilation error?
I have tried

`System.out.println("Your time in hours/minutes/seconds is: " +hours ":" +minutes ":" +seconds ":");`

Comment: System.out.println("Your time in hours/minutes/seconds is: " +hours+ ":" +minutes +":" +seconds+ ":");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing some concatenation `+` operators. Do this:

```
System.out.println("Your time in hours/minutes/seconds is: " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":");
```